# How to add authorisation token to a HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, spring-boot

I am getting a 401 unauthorized error when hitting my rest end point, this is because i have added security, i am not sure if i am doing the http headers part correctly.

the application makes use of a spring boot backend rest api, i know that it works because when I get a token via postman and use that authorisation token again in postman to access the api, it works fine.

```
getWeatherByCityAndCountry(city: string, country: string): Promise<Weather> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ this.accessToken);
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/byCity/' + city + '/' + country, {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as Weather)
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

the accessToken has been hardcoded using a token value from postman.

Comment: What's the exact error you're facing?

Comment: when trying to access the api through an angular front end I get an error 401, unauthorized.

Comment: if you console log this.accestoken is it undefined or its the proper value?

Comment: it is the proper value as I have set it to be a value of a token I retrieved using postman

Comment: are you positive the accessToken isn't expired and its related to the bearer token? e.g. its not a CORS issues by chance?

Comment: yes, if i do a get request on the rest service in post man using the same accessToken it works, so the token is not expired, i have set my token expiration at 12 hours in my back end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I recommend is adding an interceptor, to catch all requests so you don't have to manually add them every time you make a request.

```js
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    const responseType = req.responseType || 'json';
    const apiToken = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
    const authed = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + apiToken),
      responseType
    });
    const notAuthed = req.clone({
      responseType
    });
    const authReq = apiToken ? authed : notAuthed;

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Add the following to your module providers array.

```
{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true
}
```

Comment: ok this makes sense, am i correct in saying i would add functionality to log a  user in and get thus token, this interceptor will then always use said token across the application?

Comment: @SEED correct, in above example the token is saved in local.

Comment: awesome , makes sens,sure it will work fine, thanks

Comment: @SEED if you feel like this has answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: using this approach the apiToken still shows as null in the console, any ideas?

Comment: Have you registered the interceptor? I’ve update how to register the interceptor properly.

Comment: i have done so, if i consolie.log(apiToken) it is null

Comment: @SEED where are you logging and how are you retrieving you token?